# CSS Tooltips move elements

Tags: html, css

I am using some simple tooltips but they are moving my table elements slightly up or down for some reason. I've no idea why. What CCS attribute do I need to set in order for the tool tips to not do that.

```css
 /* Tooltip container */
  .tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  /* Tooltip text */
  .tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    color: #d6d6d6;
    text-align: center;
    top: -5px;
    left: 105%;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    border-radius: 6px;

    /* Position the tooltip text - see examples below! */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
  }

  /* Show the tooltip text when you mouse over the tooltip container */
  .tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
  }
```

```html
<div class="rTableRow">
  <div class="tooltip">
  <div class="rTableCellTop">Flight, Squadron</div>
    <span class="tooltiptext">Fill in the Flight you flew with and your Squadron.</span>
  </div>
  <div class="rTableCellCenter"></div>
  <div class="rTableCellLetter">(D)</div>
  <div class="rTableCellRight">
   option
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: With Tooltips]

[image: Without Tooltips]

Comment: Can you set up a stack snippet for us? It'll be easier to help out if we can see the problem happening.

Comment: Added images and some more code for you. 'Flight, Squadron' line is slightly displaced by the existence of the tooltip.

Comment: Basically did this https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp

Comment: What browser are you using? I'm on chrome and don't see any movement when that tooltip pops.

Comment: It doesn't happen when the tooltip pops, it happens when the tooltip is in the code, no matter if it is popped or not. I am using firefox and this is done in vue.

Comment: I still can't see that. So right now, in that stack snippet, you see the same issue? Shot in the dark, but do you seem the same problem if you remove `padding: 10px 5px;`?

Comment: Yes it does. It's like the tool tip is somehow inline and pushes the others out of the way.